# How to decode this json with foreach

Tags: php, json

This is the JSON

```
{
  "circuit_list": [
    {
      "_id": "58c0f378a986f808cdaf94cf", 
      "aggregation": {
        "dev_name": "ME2-D2-BOO", 
        "port": {
          "desc": "AKSES_SITE_SITE-TSEL_ME2-D2-BOO#1/2/5_200M_BOO082#CIPAKUBOO534", 
          "name": "1/2/5"
        }
      }, 
      "area": "AREA 2", 
      "site_id": "N/A", 
      "site_name": "N/A"
    }, 
    {
      "_id": "58c0f378a986f808cdaf94d0", 
      "aggregation": {
        "dev_name": "ME2-D2-BOO", 
        "port": {
          "desc": "AKSES_SITE_SITE-TSEL_ME2-D2-BOO#1/2/5_200M_BOO082#CIPAKUBOO534", 
          "name": "1/2/5"
        }
      }, 
      "area": "AREA 2", 
      "site_id": "N/A", 
      "site_name": "N/A"
    }
}
```

I already try with this code

```
$json = json_decode($url, true);

foreach($json as $value)
{
    $_id = $value->_id;

}
```

it didn't work. Please help, I need to get the value to show them on the view. Did I do this wrong? this json is difficult because i didn't understand the structure.
I usually decode json with format

```
[{"id":"1","name":"faisal"}]
```

like this and with my foreach it's working.

Comment: `foreach($json->circuit_list as $value)`?

Comment: @xmike it respond Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: remove `true` (_When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays._) or use variables as arrays! `$json['circuit_list']   $value['_id']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the second parameter of [`json_decode`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) is true, the function will return an array instead of an object. Also, you would need to loop over the `circuit_list` property of the object.

```
$json = json_decode($url); // <- remove the parameter

foreach($json->circuit_list as $value) // <- loop over circuit_list
{
    $_id = $value->_id;
}
```

Comment: how to get value of aggregation and port inside circuit_list?

Comment: i found the solution $dev_name = $value->aggregation->dev_name;

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$json = json_decode($url,true);
foreach($json['circuit_list'] as $value) 
{
    $id = $value['_id'];
}

?>
```